# Why does posting to this ASP.net MVC post to controller result in a null model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In the following code, the Product object is always getting set to null - but if I debug, I can see that the values are being posted correctly. What's going on?

Model:

```
public class Product {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewProduct(Product model) {
    if (model == null) { throw new NullReferenceException("model is null D:"); }
    // Do other things
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("NewProduct", "Home")) {

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Model</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Model)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
}
```

Comment: I will double check to see if your form is actually using post and not a get. In your controller action you specify a post but this is not specified in the form.

Comment: Definitely doing a post, I'll make that explicit in the question.

Comment: Actually, I've had a play around - the issue I'm raising (the model is null) happens with a GET as well. A mismatch between a GET form and a POST action results in a 404. So I'm leaving the question as it was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Rename the parameter on the controller action

The parameter of the controller method cannot be named the same as any of the properties of the model or the binder won't bind properly

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewProduct(Product newProduct) {
    if (newProduct == null) { throw new NullReferenceException("model is null D:"); }
    // Do other things
    return View();
}
```

Note: this comparison is case insensitive - here the parameter was `model` and the object had a `Model` property but it still bugged out.

Comment: And by "named the same" it includes capitalization and camel casing. So "UserName" and "username" are the same

Comment: Interesting, I never knew this

Comment: @Shoe, good point - I meant to mention that but left it implicit. I'll alter the answer.